# Insert fields on same level as child in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm still learning XSLT. I need help inserting fields as children to a line item node. The Field nodes need to be inserted to the preceding LineItem that occurred.
Is there a way to handle this in XSLT 1.0? i.e xpath axes preceding sibling ?

Incoming XML:

```
<Data>
<Data>
    <Field1/>
    <Field2/>
    <Field3/>
    <LineItem>
        <LineItemNum>1</LineItemNum>
    </LineItem>
    <Field>
        <HouseNumber/>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <HouseNumber/>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <HouseNumber/>
    </Field>
    <LineItem>
        <LineItemNum>2</LineItemNum>
    </LineItem>
    <Field>
        <HouseNumber/>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <HouseNumber/>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <HouseNumber/>
    </Field>
</Data>
```

```
Output needed:
  <Data>
   <Data>
    <Field1/>
    <Field2/>
    <Field3/>
    <LineItem>
        <LineItemNum>1</LineItemNum>
        <Field>
            <HouseNumber/>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <HouseNumber/>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <HouseNumber/>
        </Field>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
        <LineItemNum>2</LineItemNum>
        <Field>
            <HouseNumber/>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <HouseNumber/>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <HouseNumber/>
        </Field>
    </LineItem>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far from being trivial and I would not recommend it to a beginner. Try the following approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="field-by-item" match="Field" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::LineItem[1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data/Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Field)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LineItem">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('field-by-item', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Appreciate you response. Can you tell me what the "1" is for in LineItem[1] ?

Comment: The first one on this axis - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates